# Maximum coordinate in Dirichlet distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Suppose $X=(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ is a random vector following the Dirichlet law with a uniform concentration parameter $\alpha\geq 1$. I was wondering if there are any asymptotic results for the maximum and minimum coordinates of $X$ ? In the case of $\alpha=1$, I know that the expected value $\mathbf{E}[\max X_i] \sim n^{-1} \log n $ and $\mathbf{E}[\min X_i] \sim n^{-2}$. How do these results generalize for $\alpha > 1$ ?